# What is the jqgrid formatter actually supposed to do?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement a formatter with an editable jqgrid grid.  I've read the wiki page about it, but it doesn't really mention what it's supposed to do.  It just says that it formats.

For example, here is a piece of my code (this is from the column definition section):

```
{ name: 'daily', index: 'daily', width: 90, sorttype: "currency", editable: true, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$ " } },
```

My expectations of what a formatter should do:
Since this is a currency, not allow the user to enter letters, symbols, etc. (only numbers)
Place a dollar sign in front of the number
Put the decimal point in the proper position
Put the thousands comma in the proper position.

It is doing none of this.  So what should I be expecting from formatter?

Answer (score 0):

A jqGrid formatter is just a function that formats cell data:

```
function myformatter ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
{
    // format the cellvalue to new format
    return new_formated_cellvalue;
}
```

As you can see, it only allows formatting of the cell content for display, it does not perform any validation.

---

If you want to validate that the edited data is input in a specific format, you need to add [`editrules`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) to your colModel. For example you might use one of the following options:

> ```
> number    boolean  (true or false) if set to true, the value will be
>                    checked and if this is not a number, an error message 
>                    will be displayed.
>
> custom    boolean  if set to true allow definition of the custom checking 
>                    rules via a custom function. See below
> ```